# Uniqueness constraint causes Neo4J to hang?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, freeze, unique-constraint

This simple Cypher code, entered into the web interface on a new, empty Neo4J graph, causes the whole server to hang.

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (u:URL) ASSERT u.URL IS UNIQUE;
```

I then have to do

```
sudo service neo4j stop
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/neo4j/data/databases/graph.db
sudo service neo4j start
```

to fix it. Stopping the service takes ~1min.

The end of the debug.log shows:

```
2017-10-12 13:29:17.245+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] --- SERVER STARTED END ---
2017-10-12 13:29:56.701+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.a.i.IndexPopulationJob] Index population started: [:Book(isbn) [provider: {key=lucene, version=1.0}]]
2017-10-12 13:29:57.088+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.a.i.IndexPopulationJob] Completed node store scan. Flushing all pending updates.
BatchingMultipleIndexPopulator{activeTasks=0, executor=java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@1cf9354b[Running, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0], batchedUpdates = [], queuedUpdates = 0}
2017-10-12 13:29:57.088+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.a.i.IndexPopulationJob] Shutting down executor.
BatchingMultipleIndexPopulator{activeTasks=0, executor=java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@1cf9354b[Running, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0], batchedUpdates = [], queuedUpdates = 0}
2017-10-12 13:51:15.551+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.t.l.c.CheckPointerImpl] Check Pointing triggered by scheduler for time threshold [4]:  Starting check pointing...
2017-10-12 13:51:15.552+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.t.l.c.CheckPointerImpl] Check Pointing triggered by scheduler for time threshold [4]:  Starting store flush...
```

(It's showing attempted indexing of :Book because I tried the canonical example in the constraints docs)

Shutting down the hung server after a couple of hours of leaving it hanging triggers a stack of these errors into the debug.log:

```
2017-10-12 16:38:26.083+0000 ERROR [o.n.b.v.t.BoltProtocolV1] Failed to write response to driver Cannot write to buffer when closed
java.io.IOException: Cannot write to buffer when closed
        at org.neo4j.bolt.v1.transport.ChunkedOutput.ensure(ChunkedOutput.java:163)
        at org.neo4j.bolt.v1.transport.ChunkedOutput.writeShort(ChunkedOutput.java:94)
        at org.neo4j.bolt.v1.packstream.PackStream$Packer.packStructHeader(PackStream.java:427)
        at org.neo4j.bolt.v1.messaging.BoltResponseMessageWriter.onFailure(BoltResponseMessageWriter.java:91)
        at org.neo4j.bolt.v1.messaging.MessageProcessingHandler.publishError(MessageProcessingHandler.java:46)
        at org.neo4j.bolt.v1.messaging.MessageProcessingHandler.onFinish(MessageProcessingHandler.java:107)
        at org.neo4j.bolt.v1.runtime.BoltStateMachine.after(BoltStateMachine.java:103)
        at org.neo4j.bolt.v1.runtime.BoltStateMachine.run(BoltStateMachine.java:199)
        at org.neo4j.bolt.v1.messaging.BoltMessageRouter.lambda$onRun$3(BoltMessageRouter.java:80)
        at org.neo4j.bolt.v1.runtime.concurrent.RunnableBoltWorker.execute(RunnableBoltWorker.java:130)
        at org.neo4j.bolt.v1.runtime.concurrent.RunnableBoltWorker.run(RunnableBoltWorker.java:91)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

No processors grinding. I installed using apt-get.

I'm running Neo4J Community 3.2.6 on Ubuntu 16.04, kernel 4.4.0.

Am I missing something obvious here, or should I file a bug report?

Comment: This is not the normal behavior. Is there something in the `debug.log` ? Do you have one CPU at 100% ? Have you installed Neo4j with apt or with the tar.gz ?

Comment: Updated question with extra details.

Comment: Judging from the first log snippet, your earlier attempt to create a uniqueness constraint on `:Book(isbn)` never completed, since there should have been another log entry that looked like: `Index population completed. Index is now online: [:Book(isbn) [provider: {key=lucene, version=1.0}]]`. There is already a somewhat similar issue for index creation (https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/10251) for the same neo4j version and OS. You should probably create a new issue and add to the above issue a reference to yours.

Comment: Done, thanks. [gtihub issue](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/10276)   Do you think I should try purging Neo4J and reinstalling it? I'd like to be able to get on with development, but I don't know if it will fix the problem, and I want to be able to help track the issue down!

Comment: Yes, I would try that. Whether the same issue is repeatable after a complete purge and reinstall would be good info to add to your issue.

Comment: Purge and reinstall returns Neo4J to expected behaviour. Weird, since very little had been done to it since first install. There had been an apt-managed update to it - I wonder if that broke something? Ah well, thanks all!